# Adding the script tag before Doctype Declaration

Tags: javascript, html

I just did a little test and if I add a script in the manner illustrated below it seems to execute in most modern major browsers. It executes before the page is loaded, I was wondering if this would work across all browsers (including historic)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello world");
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am of course trying to find a way to execute a script to set a page up before any of it is loaded...any input towards this end would be greatly appreciated. Would it be wrong to use this method?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to perform before any piece of the document have been parsed?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? (And why are you using an XHTML doctype and `<html>` tag and then declaring the content type to be HTML?)

Comment: This will drop IEs to Quirks mode, I doubt you want to run your pages in IE5.5 : ).

Comment: @Pointy: Because nobody was taught the right content-type for XHTML, and even if everyone were taught it they couldn't use the knowledge years ago because IE didn't start supporting it until version 9.

Comment: I just threw that together from extracts, my apologies for the mistake! Before the page is loaded I wish to hide and unhide elements. If I use 'onload' in the body I can still see an unaltered page sometimes even if for a split second (especially if the browser was slow)...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn well my suspicion is that few XHTML pages coded in 2013 are that way for any good reason.

Comment: @user1360809 Well this won't solve that problem. Because the document won't exist when the code runs, your code won't be able to gain access to any of the page elements.

Comment: I edited it...is the code better now? What was there previously was sourced from Dreamweaver! (I BS you not...)

- Pointy, ah, I had only tested an alert!

Comment: The answer is short: don't do that.

Answer (score 5):

The script gets executed, but the the markup (any element before a DOCTYPE string) puts some browses to [quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), which means a large number of poorly documented quirks and oddities, and mess, too.

So whatever your reasons are, you should at least put the element in the first syntactically correct place, namely right after the `<head>` tag. This can hardly matter as compared with placing it at the start of the document.

Whether the placement solves your real problem is an entirely different thing. You should ask a separate question, clearly describing the problem (rather than an assumed solution), preferably illustrated by some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#conformant-documents),

> A conformant document in the HTML syntax must consist of the following
>   parts, in the **following order**:
>
> 1. Optionally, a single U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM) character.
> 2. Any number of comments and space characters.
> 3. **A doctype**.
> 4. Any number of comments and space characters.
> 5. **An html element, with its attributes (if any) and its contents (if any).**

Browsers follow these specs, and your code (even though works now) may break in the future, since
it clearly breaks the rule of order of elements.

Secondly, it's almost always better to [load the scripts last](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) for performance gain.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in the comments that you want to hide/show elements before the page is displayed and that `onload` is too slow. Try using the `DOMContentLoaded` instead is it triggers as soon as the HTML DOM is built but before all images CSS and other external references is loaded.

That has always worked for me - though I use jQuery's `ready` event to make it work cross-browser. And it keeps your HTML valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing malicious Javascript code injected exactly like this, which somehow makes a blank space at the top of a WordPress page. If you click that blank space, you're taken to a site that talks about crypto. The malicious script uses the Javascript atob() function which when then deconverted with base64 and html-escaped causes the crypto page to be loaded.

Just so you know...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).