# Enqueue JavaScript into Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

-I am trying to include JavaScript file in my plug-in. For testing I am calling a JavaScript function fun().

-My plug-in directory structure is:

**(first-plugin, (js, 'animate.js'), 'first_plugin.php')**

Above given directory format is like this (dirname, content_in_the_dir_separated_by_comma).

-Here is my main plugin file code:

```
function wl_include_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script('wl_js', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/js/animate.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}

function wl_activate_plugin() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wl_include_files');
}

//
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wl_activate_plugin');

function test() {
    $v = "<script>fun();</script>";
    echo $v;
}

//
add_action('admin_init', 'test');
```

-Here is my JavaScript file code:

```
console.log('hi, file included properly.');

function fun() {
    alert("Hey, Someone calling me.");
}
```

-I am getting following error in my console:

**ReferenceError: fun is not defined**

-Can anybody tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `admin_init()` hook is triggered before any other hook when a user accesses the admin area. This means that `test()` is being called before any part of the page is constructed. Or in other words, `fun()` would be called before even the `<html>` tag and more to the point, before `animate.js` is included in `<head>`.

test.php (main plugin file inside test plugin directory)

```
//this wp_footer hook is called once the entire front-end page body has been constructed
add_action('wp_footer', 'test');

wp_enqueue_script( 'myjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js.js');

function test()
{
    echo '<script>test();</script>';
}
```

js.js (inside same test directory)

```
function test()
{
    console.log("Function called.");
}

(function ()
{
    console.log('JavaScript successfully included.');
})();
```

Further links:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: Hey, thanks for showing interest in my question. Your solution is working. What if I want to call some javascript/JQuery code in admin_init hook?
Is there any way to include javascript file in my plugin before admin_init?

Comment: @Aviator What are you actually trying to do? Calling JavaScript before the start of a HTML document (there is no HTML document at the time of admin_init) [doesn't make logical sense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176329/adding-the-script-tag-before-doctype-declaration) and would likely lead to unexpected results.

`admin_enqueue_scripts()` would include JavaScript the same way `wp_enqueue_script()` does. Why do you need to call the included functions so early?

Comment: Oh, that's true. Makes sense. Thanks! I have to add one extra menu in Wordpress media library. `function test() {
    if (false != strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'upload.php')) {
    media_library_menu();     
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'test');` media_library_menu() will call JavaScript function. Is am I going wrong?