# Javascript inside php echo not executing?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
//Clear the cache for form values

header('Cache-Control: no store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: no store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

//Load up functions
include "recon.php";


//Create the PHP Self Function
$username = $nohours = $noitem = $ipaddr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nohours = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hours", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $noitem = 0;
    $xnoitem = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "itemselect", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($xnoitem === "item1") {
        $noitem = 1;
    }
    $ipaddr = get_client_ip();

    if(!empty($username)){
        echo "Username is not null";
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "New text!";</script>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <title> GGG Time Form </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function outputUpdate(hours)
            {
                document.querySelector('#nohours').value = hours;

                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$" + hours * 3.75;

                document.getElementById("item1").checked = false;
            }

            function xitem1()
            {
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$16";
            }
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ctext">GGG Time Order Form</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p id="warning"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                (Enter your username you login with at GGG) Username:<span style="color:red;">*</span> <input type="text" name="username">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="hourslider">Number of hours you would like to purchase: </label>
                <input type="range" name="hours" min="1" max="24" value="12" id="hourslider" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
                <output for="hourslider" id="nohours">12</output>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h3> Or select one of our packages below </h3>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="itemselect" value="item1" id="item1" onclick="xitem1()"> Day Pass $16.00
                <hr>
                <h3> Total payment owed: <p id="total">$0</p></h3>
                <input type="submit">
                <hr>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="ipbox">
            <span>For security purposes your ip address is being logged: <?php echo get_client_ip(); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

So on that logical statement below this text ( Also located in the code above) I'm wondering why when I echo out the javascript it's not changing the contents of the `<p>` element with the id of warning. I've tried looking everywhere for my answer and I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but any help would be appreciated...

```
if(!empty($username)){
        echo "Username is not null";
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "New text!";</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding the script tag before Doctype Declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176329/adding-the-script-tag-before-doctype-declaration)

Comment: Just a suggestion, since your javascript there isn't doing much, you could save that text to a variable and echo it inside the `warning <p>`. If it doesn't match that condition, the variable with the text is empty, not showing anything.

Comment: your basic problem is that it _is_ executing, but _none_ of your document has loaded yet. there is _no_ element with the id of `warning` at the point your javascript is being loaded and executed

Comment: Well I need it to dynamically change, the warning <p> is supposed to alert users that they haven't filled in the username field of the form

Comment: Echo this javascript after your HTML. It executes the getElementByID method before the element exists so it's finding nothing.

Comment: You didn't check your console for errors, did you?

Answer (score 1):

"your basic problem is that it is executing, but none of your document has loaded yet. there is no element with the id of warning at the point your javascript is being loaded and executed" ~ Watcher